# Фраза. Окончания в названиях книг или фильмов.

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Фраза: "Это из "Братьев Карамазовых", -правильна?

Comment: Не правильнА. Потому что правильно писать — "правильнО". Вы что, первый класс еще не закончили, что делаете такие позорные ошибки?

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, тут вы не правы. *Фраза (какова?) правильна* - краткое прилагательное женский род.

Comment: Ох, прошу прощения и беру свои слова назад.

Answer (score 2):

Да. Как вариант можно использовать *это из книги "Братья Карамазовы"*.

Answer (score 2):

Смотря о чем речь.

Если о пунктуации, то фразу надо написать изолировано (отдельно от поясняющего текста), у Вас непонятно использование кавычки и точки:

***Это из "Братьев Карамазовых".***

Если речь о падеже, в котором стоит название книги (филиьма и т.п.), то да, названия в этом случае склоняются. Есть, правда исключения, когда названия представляют собой развернутое определение или целое предложение.

***Это из "А зори здесь тихие".***

Тут по-другому и не скажешь.

Разумеется, всегда есть возможность добавить родовое слово (как у Марка Иза): книга, фильм, пьеса и проч., тогда вопрос снимается сам собой.