# Склонение названий произведений

Tags: грамматика, склонение, названия

Катарина из "Укрощение строптивой". 
Тут склоняется название или нет? 
Правильнее будет сказать "Катарина из "Укрощения..."?

Comment: Повтор вопроса: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: А также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20768/%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%9e%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433992/%d0%a7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%86%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9/433994#433994

Comment: Ответов много, но нет ссылок на классиков. Они на эту тему сказали что-нибудь определенное?

Answer (score 2):

Корректно: **Катарина из "Укрощения строптивой".**

Вот тут тов. Arina требовала ссылок на классиков. Розенталь в своем справочнике [(§ 188 п. 5 и 6](http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xliii.html#sect188.6)) говорит о согласовании сказуемого с подлежащим, выраженным названием. Думаю, его подход можно применить и к склонению названий. После небольшой переработки розенталевского текста у меня получилось вот что (примеры частично мои):

Если название состоит из одного слова, оно склоняется (*цитата из "Известий*").

Если название составное, все зависит от его состава:

1. если в составном названии имеется ведущее слово в форме именительного падежа, название склоняется вместе с ним (*цитата  из "Белой гвардии")*
2. если в составном названии нет ведущего слова в форме именительного падежа, то название не склоняется (*цитата из «Доживем до понедельника*"). Если результат плохо воспринимается при чтении или произнесении вслух, следует включать родовое наименование (роман, поэма, пьеса, опера и т. п.).
3. если составное название образовано двумя существительными, то в отдельных случаях название склоняется (*цитата из "Войны и мира*"), однако при этом могут появиться курьезные сочетания, например: «Двенадцать апостолов» стояли на рейде (фрегат), «Волки и овцы» распроданы. В подобных случаях следует включать родовое наименование (роман, поэма, пьеса, опера и т. п.).