# Склоняется ли название книги в виде местоимения?

Tags: склонение, названия, ономастика

Недавно обсуждал книгу Анны Борисовой (он же Борис Акунин, он же Анатолий Брусникин, он же  Г. Ш. Чхартишвили) "Там" и задался вопросом склоняется ли данное название. Например, если я хочу обсудить эпизод в романе "Там", могу ли я сказать, - "В "Таме" написано..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Местоимение-наречие**](https://lingvistics_dictionary.academic.ru/2008/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F)
Разряд местоимений, указывающих на признак действия или признак признака;
отвечают на вопросы: как? когда? где? почему? зачем? Не изменяются. Могут заменять наречия или заменяться ими.
К ним относятся: так, как, **там**, тут, где, когда, почему, потому, зачем, затем и др.

**Там** не изменяется, поэтому сказать  «В "Таме" написано...» никак нельзя.
Правильно говорить так: «В "Там" написано...», или *во второй главе книги "Там"*, или *в романе "Там"*.

Вообще-то названий, содержащих в себе "там", достаточно:
*Там, где заканчивается радуга* (С. Ахерн);
*Там алеет заря* (А. Ефремов);
*Там, откуда облака* (И. Малышев);
*Там, где кончается река* (Ч. Мартин);
*Там, где цветет полынь* (О. Вингет);
*Там, вдали* (В. Шукшин).

Думаю, что и эти названия "склонению не подлежат".
И следующие — тоже:

*Зачем?* (Н. Попов); [***Так или так***](https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/1053012/Raud_-_Tak_ili_tak.html) (Э. Рауд); *Тут и там* (Х. Хобби).

Comment: А вот такая фантазия: если бы роман носил название «Таз»?

Comment: "Бочка", "Кувшин", "Похищенная бадья", "Сковорода ближнего боя", "Ведро алмазов", "Ведро незабудок", "Поварёшка" — эти книги уже есть. Так почему же не быть такой фантазии — названию "Таз"? Прецедент существует: _Три мудреца в одном **тазу**_.

Comment: Разговор о склонении названия из одного слова ( т а м ). Вы же говорите не о тех прецедентах. И здесь, и в ответе. Какой в этом смысл, сможете объяснить?

Comment: По-моему, я написала четко: _Там не изменяется, поэтому сказать «В "Таме" написано...» никак нельзя._ И про фантастический "таз" ответила: _в "Тазу"._

Comment: А что чётко скажете о приведённых названиях? Что они доказывают?

Comment: Я имела в виду, что невозможно просклонять и эти названия: в _Таме алеет заря_, в _Таме, вдали_, в _Зачеме?_, в _Туте и таме_.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, не склоняется. На нашем сайте было несколько вопросов и ответов о склонении названий книг и других произведений.  Привожу этот список в качестве ответа, так как в комментарии он не помещается.

[Склонение названий произведений](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434332/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

[Склонение названий книг или фильмов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2)

[Фраза. Окончания в названиях книг или фильмов.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20768/%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%9e%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2)

[Читать "Отцы и дети" или "Отцов и детей"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433992/%d0%a7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%86%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9/433994#433994)